# unable to iterate over an array within my html

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a breadcrumb component for angular7 but I can't get my array to properly show into my HTML and would like some tips because I can't find it on the internet. if you would be so kind as to help me I am still new to angular and can't think of a better way to make a breadcrumb component.

my component.ts -

```
breadcrumbLists: Array <any> = [];
breadcrumburl: Array <any> = [];

constructor(private _router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.listenrouting();
}

listenrouting(): void {
    let routerUrl: string, routerList: Array < any > ;
    let i;
    let done;
    this._router.events.subscribe((router: any) => {
        routerUrl = router.urlAfterRedirects;
        if (routerUrl && typeof routerUrl === 'string') {
            this.breadcrumbLists.length = 0;
            routerList = routerUrl.slice(1).split('/');
            this.breadcrumbLists = routerList;

            if (done != false) {

                this.breadcrumbLists.forEach(bread => {

                    if (i != null) {
                        this.breadcrumburl.push([{ name: bread }, { url: i + "/" + bread }])
                    } else {
                        this.breadcrumburl.push([{ name: bread }, { url: "/" + bread }])
                    }

                    i = "/" + bread

                });
            }

            console.log("url", this.breadcrumburl)
            console.log(this.breadcrumbLists)
            done = false;
        }
    });
}
```

and then my HTML -

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <li *ngFor="let Breadcrumb of breadcrumburl">
            <a routerLink="{{Breadcrumb.url}}">{{Breadcrumb.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `Breadcrumb.url` - missed the capital `B`

Comment: if that  was it I was going to scream but it wasn't it was a mistake in my code to

Comment: it doesn't work like that but your answer works thanks I tried it because I knew they where nested array's but I thought I tried that but I don't think so because now no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm not wrong, you want to push into `breadcrumburl` array as -

```
this.breadcrumburl.push({name: bread, url: i + "/" + bread});
```

Currently, you created nested arrays & pushed 2 elements in all nested arrays in `breadcrumburl`